# How to get the last unexpected exit code of the docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to maintain a project, and set `restart=always` to all the docker service.

But my API host crashed twice today, I look through the logs `docker logs -f <container-id>`. No cue found about the crash reason.

The logs guide me the main process was killed then restarted.

how to get the last unexpected exit code ?

Thanks.

Comment: One option is to start a shell instead of the actual service, and then manually run the service. If it crashes, you can simply examine `$?` for the exit code, since you'll still be in the shell in the container.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the IDs and exit codes of exited containers with this command:

```
docker inspect --format "{{.ID}} {{.State.ExitCode}}" $(docker ps -a --filter "status=exited" --format {{.ID}})
```

Explanation:

- `docker ps -a --filter "status=exited" --format {{.ID}}` will output containers IDs which state is `exited`
- `docker inspect --format "{{.ID}} {{.State.ExitCode}}"` then will print IDs and exit codes of those containers